# how to detect a DNS resolution on hostname

Tags: dns, nslookup

If someone does a nslookup on http://foo.bar, can I set up something on the foo.bar server machine to detect that someone tried to DNS lookup the hostname? Are there any requests coming to foo.bar that I can see and detect their origin?

Comment: may i know which DNS server using in foo.bar

Comment: In general - no. There may be many servers in between caching data. Theoretically if you run the DNS yourself and put timeout to minimum you *might* get the requests, but it's still not guaranteed in any way.

Answer (score 1):

No, because (generally) DNS lookup of the `foo.bar` hostname is not at all related to `foo.bar` server machine.